# Read Notification via web

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I want to implement a push notification service. The idea is to use the GCM Service. Is it possible to read the notifications both via web app (the app is written in php using laravel) and via mobile app for the authenticated users using the same technology?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible, I also see this [tutorial](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-send-push-notifications-using-gcm-service/) that can help you to achieve that. It also use PHP as a sample, so it seems like your work will be easier:)

It explains here the basic steps that you need to achieve push notification. It has a sample code and a screenshot to make you understand more the content of this tutorial.

In developing this application, it involves two parts, a GCM Server Application that create Web application using Php to send message to User via GCM Cloud server and GCM Client Application that create Android application which receive messages sent from GCM Server Web App.

For more information you can also check this links:

- [Implementing Push Messaging for Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web?hl=en)
- [How to send push notification to web browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33687298/how-to-send-push-notification-to-web-browser)