# How to Send,Schedule Notification using HTML 5 Notification - Web APIs?

Tags: javascript, html, web-notifications

Hi can we Schedule  Notification using Web APIs and send them on desired time .I have a CMS application where user can Schedule  and send push notification for their mobiles apps ,i'm looking something similar to that using html 5 web notification .

Comment: Probably you don't want to use Web notifications alone, as you wrote, but together with the Push API. There isn't a way to schedule notifications with the Push API, you must use cron or something like that on your server. Otherwise use one of the many web push notifications services that offer that feature.

Comment: Please mark this question as duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33687298/how-to-send-push-notification-to-web-browser?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trigger a Google Chrome Notification.

I don't know what a CMS is, but if you are using a HTML web page or Extension, it can trigger a notification

You can refer to this: [Chrome desktop notification example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271156/chrome-desktop-notification-example)