# GCM for web, notification dissappear after x seconds

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, push

i am developing a push notificacftion system with GCM. I have seen that all the notifications dissappear after x seconds.

How can i do to make them permanent until the users clicks it or close it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [time_to_live parameter](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#ttl), to specify the maximum lifespan of a message. The value of this parameter must be a duration from 0 to 2,419,200 seconds, and it corresponds to the maximum period of time for which GCM will store and try to deliver the message.

Check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#send-downstream) to know the different parameters that you can set in your GCM.

Also,Check this [link](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web?hl=en) and [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33687298/how-to-send-push-notification-to-web-browser) for more information.

Comment: but this is to specify the time that the push notification will be stored in the servers if the computer is offline. I am looking for another thing... Now when i send a push, this push dissappear after x seconds, it should have to be fixed until the user click on it

Comment: Just for confirming, you only use GCM for web? not on android or IOS?
I really like to help you, but all information that I see about this is always for android. I'm still looking for other information that can help this problem.

Comment: yes, only for web. I am having the same problem, all the info is for android, for web there are a pair of examples and thats it.

Comment: this is a live example of gcm for web. https://gauntface.github.io/simple-push-demo/   , if you use it on desktop the push disappear, but in mobile no