# How to get Web Notification when browser or tab is closed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, push-notification, notifications

I need to get a Web Notification when the browser is closed or the browser tab is closed.

My code is below; the notifications work when the site is open, but not when the browser or tab is closed:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Display browser Notification from Web Application Demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

var articles = [
["HOW TO GET RS 2000 LENSKART GIFT VOUCHER FOR 890 USING NEARBUY LENSKART OFFER.","http://www.findyoursolution.in/get-rs-2000-lenskart-gift-voucher-890-using-nearbuy-lenskart-offer/"],
["HOW TO GET RS 100 CASHBACK ON RS 500 RECHARGE AND BILLS PAYMENT AT PAYZAPP APP.","http://www.findyoursolution.in/get-rs-100-cashback-rs-500-recharge-bills-payment-payzapp-app/"],
["HOW TO GET 500MB 3G-2G DATA FOR FREE BY USING AIRCEL FREE INTERNET TRICK","http://www.findyoursolution.in/get-500mb-3g2g-data-free-using-aircel-free-internet-trick/"],
["HOW TO AVAIL NEARBUY PVR CINEMA OFFER","http://www.findyoursolution.in/avail-nearbuy-pvr-cinema-offer/"],
["GIVE STRATEGIC IMPORTANCE TO INDIAN TELECOM SECTOR: DELOITTE HASKINS SELLS ON BUDGET EXPECTATIONS.","http://www.findyoursolution.in/give-strategic-importance-to-indian-telecom-sector-deloitte-haskins-sells-on-budget-expectations/"],
["AIRTEL TRICK UNLIMITED GUJRAT 3G 4G UDP TRICK","http://www.findyoursolution.in/airtel-trick-unlimited-gujrat-3g-4g-udp-trick-4920012-port/"],
["HOW TO DOWNLOAD MYVODAFONE APP AND GET 100MB 3G DATA.","http://www.findyoursolution.in/download-myvodafone-app-get-100mb-3g-data/"],
["HOW TO GET RS 20 FREE RECHARGE FROM AGROSTAR APP.","http://www.findyoursolution.in/get-rs-20-free-recharge-agrostar-app/"],
["WHAT ARE THE NAMES OF SNOW WHITE SEVEN DWARFS.","http://www.findyoursolution.in/names-snow-whites-seven-dwarfs/"]
];    

setTimeout(function(){ 
var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
var title=articles[x][0];
var desc='Most popular article.';
var url=articles[x][1];
notifyBrowser(title,desc,url);
}, 200000);    

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () 
{

if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
{
Notification.requestPermission();
}

document.querySelector("#notificationButton").addEventListener("click", function(e)
{
var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
var title=articles[x][0];
var desc='Most popular article.';
var url=articles[x][1];
notifyBrowser(title,desc,url);
e.preventDefault();
});

//===================================
setInterval(function(e){ 
var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
var title=articles[x][0];
var desc='Most popular article.';
var url=articles[x][1];
notifyBrowser(title,desc,url);
e.preventDefault();

}, 5000);
//===================================
});

function notifyBrowser(title,desc,url) 
{
if (!Notification) {
console.log('Desktop notifications not available in your browser..'); 
return;
}
if (Notification.permission !== "granted")
{
Notification.requestPermission();
}
else {
var notification = new Notification(title, {
icon:'http://i2.wp.com/www.findyoursolution.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/cropped-Logo-512.jpg?fit=180%2C180',
body: desc,
});

// Remove the notification from Notification Center when clicked.
notification.onclick = function () {
window.open(url);      
};

// Callback function when the notification is closed.
notification.onclose = function () {
console.log('Notification closed');
};    
}
}

</script>    

<style type="text/css">
.hover{background-color: #cc0000}
 #container{ margin:0px auto; width: 800px} 
.button {
 font-weight: bold;
    padding: 7px 9px;
    background-color: #5fcf80;
    color: #fff !important;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    border-width: 1px 1px 3px !important;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #3ac162;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: -moz-inline-stack;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    zoom: 1;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1) inset;
}
.authorBlock{border-top:1px solid #cc0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<h1>Display browser Notification from Web Application Demo</h1>  

<h4>Click notification button</h4>
<a href="#"  id="notificationButton" class="button">Notification</a>
</div>   

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please explain more? Do you want to notify user when he is going to close tab (Or clocked the close tab button)?

Comment: Yes If I am Close Browser then need to come Notification But in Above Code Not Coming Notification When Browse Close

Comment: Onbeforeunload Is The Event You'Re Looking For - Maybe - Hard To Say Because I Don'T Know What Your Code Has To Do With Your Question

Comment: try this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33687298/how-to-send-push-notification-to-web-browser

Comment: I have reworded your question to make it a bit more readable. If you have any more clarification, the please feel free to [edit] your question to improve it further.

Comment: hey @Jitesh have you got solution for that? i also looking for same.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you can listen to `onbeforeunload`  or `onunload` to detect when the user is closing the tab or clicked on `go back` button.

Here is a simple [example](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onbeforeunload)

There are some ways to do it, you can set the `onbeforeunload` as an HTML attribute, like:

```
<body onbeforeunload="return showAlert()">
```

*Note: showAlert() is a function that will return string, and the string will be the message just in some browsers (I saw, just Microsoft Edge is not supporting the custom message)*

Or you can do it by addEventListener. But you can't have your own message on Firefox or Chrome *(Edge will show your message that your function will return, it should be a string)*

For

Comment: I am not getting Notification When Browser is closed. How can I Get Notification When Browser or tab is Close. You can Run My Code And Check

Comment: @KarthiVenture Right, but He said: **How to get Web Notification when I have close Browser or Close Tab**, and the only way you have access to *browser close event* is using `onbeforeunload` or `onunload`.

Comment: yea right but notification differ from alert right? `onbeforeunload` just say STAY or LEAVE . @Kermani

Comment: @KarthiVenture, Yes, web notifications are different, but the only way to access user browser "close" event is onbeforeunload  or onunload

Comment: @KarthiVenture Here there is a very good article from David Walsh about **Web Notifications API** https://davidwalsh.name/demo/notifications-api.php