# Browser push notifications with Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, google-chrome, browser, push-notification

I'm working on a web app with Django (Python3), and I need to make a push notification system that notify a specific user even if his browser is closed.

So I need some advice to know how and where to begin, thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33687298/how-to-send-push-notification-to-web-browser

Answer (score 0):

You can use `webpush` library which gives web notification features.

You can install this library using `pip install django-webpush`.
this work for django framework.

If you want to use for python than use `pywebpush` and install using command `pip install pywebpush`