# why javascript notification not showing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, push-notification, notifications, web-push

I am using below example.it show show me `chrome` notification default.but when I click on button it doesn't show show me notification why ?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification

I am using `83 v chrome` and mac
[image]

[image]

I used two example first one is `simple` and second one to get permission then show .both are not working

here is my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-tdd-9kto3?file=/src/App.js:249-1123

```
<button
        onClick={() => {
          var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");

          // another example

          // if (!("Notification" in window)) {
          //   alert("This browser does not support desktop notification");
          // }

          // // Let's check whether notification permissions have already been granted
          // else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
          //   // If it's okay let's create a notification
          //   var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
          // }

          // // Otherwise, we need to ask the user for permission
          // else if (Notification.permission !== "denied") {
          //   Notification.requestPermission().then(function(permission) {
          //     // If the user accepts, let's create a notification
          //     if (permission === "granted") {
          //       var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
          //     }
          //   });
          // }
        }}
      >
        notify
      </button>
```

Comment: Hi I'm guessing there should be way more code in there such as user-permission and more. please see links https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/push-notifications/  |  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33687298/how-to-send-push-notification-to-web-browser |

Comment: @HalilÇakar we can also show notification without  web notification it is native javascript

Comment: I know it is but as far as know it still needs a permission process right?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your system has allowed notifications, in MacOS need to enable notifications from system preferences. using following steps

**for MacOS**

system preferences -> Notifications & Focus -> Click on Browser from list -> Allow Notification.

Answer (score 1):

This is a permission issue - your test code is running inside an `<iframe>` which is not allowed - same applies to non-https environments, mentioned here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification

add a `console.log` to the requestPermission promise:

```
Notification.requestPermission().then(function (permission) {
            console.log(permission)
});
```

will log `denied`

Comment: but chrome default notification not coming

Comment: you are correct ..!! but on local there should be a  default notification come  after using this `var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
`

Comment: see this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OMXtJ0USM8s

Comment: using these two line will show notification .but in my chrome it is not showing ` Notification.requestPermission();
new Notification("Hi there!")
`

Comment: `Notification.requestPermission(); new Notification("Hi there!")`  will never work btw - requestPermission() is promise based.